# Edge browser has SCRIPT70: Permission denied xdrpc.html after authentication in Linkedin popup

Tags: linkedin-api, microsoft-edge, linkedin-jsapi

I am using the Linkedin Javascript SDK to handle a form that users can populate from their Linkedin accounts.

Here is what's happening:

1. User reaches page and clicks "populate form from linkedin" button
2. Linkedin JS auth popup opens
3. User enters credentials
4. Popup redirects to https://platform.linkedin.com/js/xdrpc.html
5. Nothing loads and authentication cycle does not complete, though Linkedin the login succeeds.
6. If this is done with the console open in the popup, you will see:

`SCRIPT70: Permission denied xdrpc.html`

The Edge team claimed to have fixed a similar issue that was affecting 3rd party logins. See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4074588/windows-10-update-kb4074588. I am using that version of Edge though and this problem still occurs.